# In Nightwatch, check for element that gets added on page load

Tags: nightwatch.js

For some Nightwatch tests, I'm executing the following js in the before (all) step:

```
(function () {
    var x = document.createElement('script');
    x.type = 'text/javascript';
    x.onload = function () {
        var y = document.createElement('div');
        y.className = 'myClassLoaded';
        $('body').append(y);
    };
    x.src = 'https://myScript.js';
    document.head.append(x);
})();
```

When I use a long enough pause, I can inspect the Chrome browser window, and I can see the new div w/ class "myClassLoaded" exists as expected.

However, when I check for the element programatically, this element never gets found:

```
elements: {
    myClassLoaded: {
        selector: 'div.myClassLoaded'
    }
...
},
commands: {
    ...
    .waitForElementPresent('@myClassLoaded', 30000);
}
```

Is there a problem searching for an element that isn't originally part of the DOM?

Comment: What exception do you get? The elements are located in current dom, so it is supposed to work

Comment: Timed out while waiting for element <div.myClassLoaded> to be present for 60000 milliseconds. - Expected "found" but got: "not found"

Comment: You are running the tests in browser?